# What is the relationship between contact and account?

Tags: account, standard-objects

What is the relationship between contact and account?

If contact and account have master-detail relationship then why is account not a mandatory field while creating a new contact ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Peter's reply to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28624/relationship-between-account-and-contact).

> **Standard Relationships**
>
> If we (salesforce.com) provide you with a relationship between two
>   objects, that is a standard relationship. Not lookup, not
>   master-detail.
>
> [...]
>
> I like to categorize these in their own separate place independent of
>   lookup/master-detail. In fact, anything standard follows the same
>   rule: it behaves exactly the way that salesforce.com wants it to
>   behave to fit the particular purpose of that standard thing.
>
> [The] Account-Contact relationship [...] is a little like lookup, a
>   little like Master-Detail, but fundamentally behaves the way it does
>   because we decided it should.

Comment: Are there other objects which have this standard relationship ?