# Confused with 2 scenarios on Contacts and Accounts

Tags: owd

I am beginner to salesforce and confused with accounts and Contacts relationship. Please clear me on the below scenarios,

1. If Account and Contacts are set to private in OWD settings, users cannot see the accounts as it is private unless the above role Hierarchy(I am clear here), Does happens same with the contacts?
2. If Account is Shared and contacts are private, Does users get access to contacts who have access to accounts? or still Private?

Can you bit explain me how contacts and Accounts are related to each other in Salesforce

Answer (score 0):

*If Account and Contacts are set to private in OWD settings, users cannot see the accounts as it is private unless the above role Hierarchy(I am clear here), Does happens same with the contacts?*

> If contact record is associated with Account. Objects behave like
>   Master-Detail relationship. All the permission will be inherited to
>   underlined contacts from Account.

*If Account is Shared and contacts are private, Does users get access to contacts who have access to accounts? or still Private?*

> User will be able to see Contacts underlined the Account (as permission
>   will be inherited from Account) also but, record edit, delete
>   capability, field accessibility will be controlled through user
>   profile and role hierarchy.
>   Contacts which are not associated to Account will be private.

Here have been similar question 2 years back: [Relationship between account and contact](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28624/relationship-between-account-and-contact)

Comment: Thanks Ashwani, i understand from your answer for the first scenario, even both are set to private, contacts were able to see by other users right? ( Just because of contacts are associated to Accounts, as it have MD relationship and even no sharing access on Accounts) Please correct me.

Comment: @Geetha if both are private then Account and its contact records can be seen by shared user only.

Comment: Now I am much more better in understanding the relation between Accounts and Contacts. Thanks for the help @Ashwani.