# Field update from child to parent (Account To contact) using workflow?

Tags: administration

We update the parent record with a workflow field update only if the relationship is master-detail. If it is a look-up relationship, then it is not possible. we know that the `Account and contact` relationship is a standard relationship. it's not a lookup nor master-detail relationship. So for workflow  `Account and contact` relationship behaves like a lookup?. then what about the `roll-up summary` field. when the relationship behaves like a lookup and when master-detail relationship?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28624/relationship-between-account-and-contact

Comment: I read this before.  it does not help with my question.  Sometimes it behaves like a Master-detail relationship for roll-up summary and sometimes like  Lookup?