# why do I see controlled by parent sharing setting for contact?

Tags: lookup, sharing, relationships, org-wide-defaults

Why do I see controlled by parent sharing settings for contact even though the relationship between account and contact is only lookup. I tried to create a lookup between Account and a custom object and checked the sharing settings. But there I could not find the controlled by parent sharing settings listed?

Comment: Saleforce functionality is "uneven" for their historic core objects. You will find many special cases such as this across the entire set of old core objects.

Answer (score 0):

As per salesforce standard functionality, we have an option for contact as **controlled by parent** sharing and its working as designed but this option is not available for custom objects when they have lookup relationship with account object.

When a custom object is on the detail side of a master-detail relationship with a standard object, its organization-wide default is set to Controlled by Parent and it is not editable.

Refer the [Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28624/relationship-between-account-and-contact#:%7E:text=Account%20and%20contact%20have%20a,contact%20will%20be%20also%20deleted.) have clear explanation about the account contact relationship

Refer the help [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_sharing.htm&type=5) for Internal Organization-Wide Sharing Defaults